# how to change HomeButton Hilight Color when press

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

i use Sherlock Actionbar

1, i wanna change Home Button BG when i press from blue to Red

2, i wanna change HomeAsUp icon (white arrow) any idea ?

[image]
Home button

[image]
pressed

here is created this actionbar code

```
extends SherlockFragmentActivity

public ActionBar actionBar;

this.actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
this.actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
this.actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
this.actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can change this by specifying your own `actionBarItemBackground` attribute in your theme.

For example,

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/my_cool_drawable</item>
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/my_cool_drawable</item>
</style>
```

and then specify `Theme.MyTheme` in the manifest for your activity.

Comment: Can we use the selector for home icon and up-indicator(< sign), to have different pressed and non pressed drawables. In the manifest, i am giving for activity, android:icon="@drawable/action_bar_home" where action_bar_home is a drawable selector, and <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/action_bar_home_as_up_indicator</item>  , but  only one state is displayed irrespective of pressed/non-pressed state.

Comment: No, neither the home icon nor "up" icon reflects state.

Answer (score 2):

usually when you want to create this behavior in Android, you need to create a new `selector` file (xml in `/drawable` folder).

in that file what you want to do is choose the different states for the button and choose the different images for them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_image" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/regular_image"></item>

</selector>
```

**edit:**

you need to do this in the actionbarSherlock library of course.